# How to prevent io:format from outputting its ASCII characters representation?

Tags: erlang

I have the following line:

```
io:format("~p~n",[<<40,45,50,51>>]).
```

It will outout

```
<<"(-23">>
```

How can I force it to print as <<40,45,50,51>> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   > io:format("~w~n",[<<40,45,50,51>>]).
   <<40,45,50,51>>
```

Here is [controls sequences](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html) for output.